# Having "parse error on input ‘->’" in a case of

Tags: haskell

I'm having a weird error in this simple haskell code. 
I confirm I'm using spaces everywhere and I don't see any problem with indentation.

Am I missing something to have this syntax error?

```hs
    it "I can play with Maybe a bit" $ do
      let b = Just "whatever"

      let res = case b of
        Just val -> "There is a value, and it is a value" --parse error on input ‘->’
        Nothing  -> "There is nothing!"

      res `shouldBe` "There is a value, and it is a value"
```

Comment: Try with (Just val)

Comment: The body of a let (in do) must be indented father than the variable you are defining.  So indent your cases father than `res`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The indentation level of the cases should be at least one space more than the start of the variable name of the let statement, like:

```
let res = case b of
     Just val -> "There is a value, and it is a value"
     Nothing  -> "There is nothing!"
```

If you write it on the same level as where `res` starts, it is parsed as if it is part of the `let` block, and not of the `case` in the `let` block.
Similarly, if you write it less indented than `res`, it is parsed as if it is part of the `do` block, and not of the `case`.

Comment: (Technically, on the same level it would be a part of `let`, not of `do` or `case`.)